# Unable to set up Stack Overflow Team Trial

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

I am attempting to register for and get a 30 day trial of Stack Overflow Teams setup for my company.

I go to the product->teams page.  I enter my information and click submit. Later I receive an email from the Stack Overflow telling me there are just a few more steps to setup my 30 day trial.    This email has a nice big blue button that says "Complete Teams Sign-up".

Clicking this button takes me back to the original Stack Overflow => Product =>Teams page that I started at.  Silly me, I began the process again...a couple of times...somehow expecting this to be different.  Unfortunately this seems to be an endless loop.

There is unfortunately no phone number, email, or chat available to access anyone who could possibly describe what I need to do next to "Complete Teams Sign-up".  This is a really bad customer experience so far.

Any answers or suggestions would be greatly appreciated as I would really like to trial the product for our team.

Comment: We're currently looking into the issue. Can you e-mail us at teams-support at stackoverflow dot com with the team name and slug you tried to create? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This issue is now resolved. The code for tracking sales leads was causing an issue with the Teams sign up process and has now been fixed.